# Camera Calibration - Zhang vs. Gold Standard

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

What are the dis/advantages of using the *Gold Standard* algorithm described in *Multiple View Geometry (Hartley and Zisserman)*, with respect to using the other popular algorithm described by *Zhang* in *A Flexible New technique for Camera Calibration*? I understand the main difference between the two algorithms, but I don't know which one is better and why?

Answer (score 3):

The *Gold Standard Algorithm* (or DLT) requires a non-coplanar target, most likely composed of orthogonal planes.

*Zhang* requires multiple views of a planar target. That's easier to create physically (might just be a printed checkerboard mounted on a planar surface).